# Send input value to a separate component on button press - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, components

I have two components both linked to the same module:

`angular.module('app', []);`

The first Component is a simple input field and button

```
angular.module('app').component('myInput', {

    template: '<input data-ng-model="$ctrl.value"/>' +
              '<button data-ng-click="$ctrl.post()">Post</button>',

    controller: function MyInputController(){
        this.value = "";
        this.post = function(){
            // get this.value from input and send to other component
        };
    }

});
```

The second component is just a repeating P tag based on an array in the controller

```
angular.module('app').component('myOutput', {

    template: '<p data-ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.data">{{ item.value }}</p>',

    controller: function MyOutputController(){
        this.data = [{value: "Example Data"}];
        /* 
           When this receives the data from the other component
           it will push() it into this.data
        */
    }
});
```

How do I get the `$ctrl.post()` method of the `<my-input/>` component to send data to the other `<my-output/>` component so that it can `push()` it into it's `data` array and be picked up by the `data-ng-repeat`?

Alernatively, is it possible to `push()` directly into the other component's `controller.data` array?

I mean, they are both just normal old Objects when it comes down to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In order to pass data between different scopes you can:

**1)** Store this data in angularjs [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)([provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)) and inject it via [DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in your controllers. In my opinion it is the best way if your components are located far from each other.

**2)** Use [scope propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (`$scope.emit()` or `$scope.broadcast()`) to send and receive data between different scopes. But I don't think it's a good idea if your components are not in "ancestor <-> descendant" relationship. In your case you can create a parent controller for both of your controllers to which you'll send data from `my-input` component, catch it via `$scope.on()` and then send to `my-output`. Otherwise you can use `$rootScope` to communicate between your components.

**3)** Use data binding between parent and child scope of directive/component (for more details read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)). In you case it is also not a very good idea considering your components are not parent and child.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks @GProst. Looks like I am going about this in the wrong way then. I imagined the process to be similar to that of ReactJS where passing information between components is relatively simple. Is it preferred practice to use parent / child propagation with `$broadcast` and `$emit` rather than using the `$rootscope`?

Comment: Don't know about these two practices, but I prefer to avoid broadcasts as such, especially on long distances. Because it's hard to debug and maintain later. You need to look for all of this path of events, which may be confusing. So I use services and data binding between parent and child (one-way data binding is more preferred).